# Problem with running different programs the Start - Run menu

Tags: windows, command-line

When I try to `run` Chrome via Start → Run → "chrome", I succeed.

However, I fail when I'm trying to run the `Beyond Compare` program via Start → Run → "bcompare", as I saw the executable is `bcompare.exe`.

Why is that?

Comment: What happens when you type "beyond..."  Perhaps Windows is searching the display name, not the file name

Comment: I receive the same error

Comment: What version of windows is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running programs by just their name, Windows traditionally searches all directories listed in the `%PATH%` environment variable.

```
C:\> set path
PATH=C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32;C:\Program Files\PuTTY;C:\Perl;C:\Program Files\Python
C:\>
```

Since many programs install to their own directories, adding everything to `%PATH%` would be very complicated. For this, some Windows components – including the *Run...* dialog – search a second location, called **[App Paths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee872121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**. For example, when you installed Chrome, it registered itself in the Registry under `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\Chrome.exe`. You can see it with Registry Editor (run `regedit`).

When you try to run `bcompare`, it fails because Beyond Compare has *not* registered itself under App Paths. If you want, you can create the key and values manually with Regedit:

- key `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion`

  - subkey `App Paths`

    - subkey `bcompare.exe`

      - value `(default)` with data `C:\Program Files\..........\bcompare.exe`
        Replace `.....` with the correct path, of course.

Comment: You are a genius, thanks, where did You learn that? can You recommend me something to make better use of regedit? thanks in advance

Comment: Paths have been a standard part of Windows OSes for quite some time. This information is just something you pick up over time and with experience.

Comment: "...something you pick up over years of fixing Windows problems for yourself, your family, friends, "friends", teachers, and random guys on IRC/forums/SU."

Comment: LOL @ " "friends" ".